# Zend Framework set HTTP response code from inside a Handler

Tags: zend-framework, rest, frameworks, handler

I'm developing a REST API using Zend Framework 1.12.3. I would like to know whether it's possible to set a HTTP response code from inside a Handler.

I'm using the Handler to check the "Accept" header. In case the requested format type is not supported, I should set a 415 HTTP error (Unsupported Media Type). However, I'm not able to set a response code from inside the Handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you mean by handler?

You can set a response code anywhere you have access to the Response object.

Technically, you can access the Response object nearly anywhere (after Bootstrap, at least) using:

```
$response = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getResponse();
```

The set your response code using:

```
$response->setHttpResponseCode($code);
```

It's most natural to do this in controllers since each controller already has a reference to the Response object:

```
$this->_response
```